# Join result of crosstab to main query

Tags: postgresql, query, subquery, pivot

I'm trying to get this column structure:

```
| id | name | main_image | rating | shop_names | prices | urls | 2 | 3 |
```

My table structure looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    category_id INT REFERENCES categories(id) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    main_image CHAR(60) NULL,
    rating float(2) DEFAULT 0.0 NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE shops (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE shops_and_products (
    shop_id INT REFERENCES shops(id) NOT NULL,
    product_id INT REFERENCES products(id) NOT NULL,
    cost INT NOT NULL,
    url VARCHAR NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE products_and_characteristics (
    product_id INT REFERENCES products(id) NOT NULL,
    characteristic_id INT REFERENCES characteristics(id) NOT NULL,
    value VARCHAR NOT NULL
);
```

So far my query look like this:

```
SELECT "pr"."id", "pr"."name", "pr"."main_image", "pr"."rating", 
        array_agg(sh.name) AS "shop_names", 
        array_agg(snp.cost) AS "prices", 
        array_agg(snp.url) AS "urls",
        "2", "3"
FROM "products" AS "pr" 
LEFT JOIN "shops_and_products" AS "snp" ON ("snp"."product_id" = "pr"."id")
LEFT JOIN "shops" AS "sh" ON ("sh"."id" = "snp"."shop_id")
LEFT JOIN crosstab('SELECT product_id, characteristic_id, value 
                    FROM products_and_characteristics
                    WHERE characteristic_id IN (2,3)
                    ORDER BY characteristic_id') 
          AS ct ("pr_id" int, "2" varchar, "3" varchar) 
          ON ("pr_id" = "pr"."id")
WHERE (("pr"."category_id" = 1) AND ("pr"."id" > -1))
GROUP BY "pr"."id"
ORDER BY "pr"."popularity" DESC
```

But I get this error while runnning it:

`column "ct.2" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Which is very odd to me, since there aren't supposed to be any arrays. How can I change my query to acomplish my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's typically best (cheapest, simplest), to join to additional tables *after* aggregating. Like:

```
SELECT *, "2", "3"
FROM  (
   SELECT pr.id, pr.name, pr.main_image, pr.rating
        , pr.popularity   -- not in your table definition (?)
        , array_agg(sh.name)  AS shop_names
        , array_agg(snp.cost) AS prices
        , array_agg(snp.url)  AS urls
   FROM   products                 pr 
   LEFT   JOIN shops_and_products  snp ON snp.product_id = pr.id
   LEFT   JOIN shops               sh  ON sh.id = snp.shop_id
   WHERE  pr.category_id = 1
   AND    pr.id > -1
   GROUP  BY pr.id
   ) sub
LEFT  JOIN crosstab(
     'SELECT product_id, characteristic_id, value 
      FROM   products_and_characteristics
      WHERE  characteristic_id IN (2,3)
      ORDER  BY characteristic_id'
   ) AS ct (id int, "2" text, "3" text) USING (id)
ORDER  BY popularity DESC;  -- not in your table definition (?)
```

Aside: I wouldn't use numbers as column names. I'd use legal names like `char2` ...

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry about the popularity column, I removed it accidentally while copying